# Unity3D, Monodevelop stuck minimized

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine, windowing

I'm not sure how it happened, but it appears to be a persistent bug. Whenever I try to launch Monodevelop by double-clicking on one of my scripts in the assets browser, Monodevelop gets launched, but remains minimized. When I attempt to restore it (by clicking on its part of the bottom bar), the state of the button changes, but Monodevelop does not appear. I've attempted to restart Unity to fix this issue, and that didn't help. Has anyone else come across this? Maybe there's a fix? Should I delete some config files so they get reset? (if so, which ones)

System: ASUS Laptop - Vista64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this is very simple, try this out.

1) Right click the application which is minimized.

2) select the "minimize" option in the list.

3) Now select the "maximize" option in the list.

4) Here the application will open(maximize)...

If you're still having problems tell me.

Comment: Got it! Sorry, I guess I've just never run into that problem before! (Thought it was a Unity problem, not a Windows problem). Gotta wait another 9 minutes to accept your answer though, just because technicalities.

Comment: i thought unity3d was an application?  anyways, thanks im new to stack overflow

Comment: Yeah, unity3d is an application, and I thought the problem was with the application not my operating system.

Comment: Oh, lolz no.  And sometimes you should ensure that your computer's operating system has enough space, or else it will load slower...